# How do I get the entire html code from a Weebly website?

Tags: html, weebly

I was thinking about getting started creating my own website with weebly.com.  If I eventually want to move my website to a different host is there a way to do that?  When I edit the html code it seems like weebly doesn't show you the whole code that's being used.
For example I just see:
`<div id="main"><div class="container">{content}</div></div>`
Instead of the `<img src>` or `<p>` that are actually on my page?

Is there any way I can see the full code or should I choose a different editor?

Comment: "view source" in your browser. However, that's not a very practical way to go about it. Weebly likely isn't producing optimal HTML in the first place.

Comment: You can use the developer console, accessible from most browsers. ctrl+shift+j for Chrome, F12 for IE/Edge, etc. Then go to sources and click on the (should be) index.html to see all code it will let you. Your CSS should populate in a similar pane as "Styles".

Comment: Also, Weebly sucks. They won't let you integrate PHP, Databasing, and generally exclude JavaScript and other potential coding you might want to throw into your site. Build it from the ground up using HTML and CSS (possibly BootStrap) to learn as much as you can about design and how the elements fit together, then bring in PHP and JavaScript in small doses to see how you like it.

Answer (score 2):

In your site editor, make sure you're on the SETTINGS tab, select GENERAL, scroll down, select ARCHIVE. Enter your email address and click EMAIL ARCHIVE. A link to download your zipped archive file will be mailed to you.